# Remove Symbols Using Selenium Scraper (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

Below is a selenium web scraper that loops through the different tabs of this [website page](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=y&type=8&season=2018&month=0&season1=2018&ind=0), selects the "export data" button, downloads the data, adds a "yearid" column, then loads the data into a MySQL table.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


button_text_to_url_type = {
    'dashboard': 8,
    'standard': 0,
     'advanced': 1,
     'batted_ball': 2,
     'win_probability': 3,
     'pitch_type': 4,
     'pitch_values': 7,
     'plate_discipline': 5,
     'value': 6
}

download_dir = os.getcwd()
profile = FirefoxProfile("C:/Users/PATHTOFIREFOX")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'text/csv')
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)


today = datetime.today()
for button_text, url_type in button_text_to_url_type.items():

    default_filepath = os.path.join(download_dir, 'Fangraphs Leaderboard.csv')
    desired_filepath = os.path.join(download_dir,
                                    '{}_{}_{}_Leaderboard_{}.csv'.format(today.year, today.month, today.day,
                                                                         button_text))

    driver.get(
        "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type={}&season=2018&month=0&season1=2018&ind=0&team=&rost=&age=&filter=&players=".format(
            url_type))
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Export Data').click()
    if os.path.isfile(default_filepath):
        os.rename(default_filepath, desired_filepath)
        print('Renamed file {} to {}'.format(default_filepath, desired_filepath))
    else:
        sys.exit('Error, unable to locate file at {}'.format(default_filepath))

    df = pd.read_csv(desired_filepath)
    df.str.replace('%', '')
    df["yearid"] = datetime.today().year
    df.to_csv(desired_filepath)

    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}"
                           .format(user="walker",
                                   pw="password",
                                   db="data"))
    df.to_sql(con=engine, name='fg_test_hitting_{}'.format(button_text), if_exists='replace')

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

The scraper works perfectly, however, when I download the data, some columns download data with a % sign after an integer (i.e., 25%) which throws off my data types in MySQL. I have tried using df.str.replace('%','') and df.replace('%',''), but both have been unsuccessful. When scraping the data into a Pandas data frame, is it possible to alter the columns that contain the % symbol so that it just shows the integer? Should I be incorporating this into my loop or can I just add a line of code after I've established a Pandas data frame? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.replace` doesn't do inplace replacements. It returns the modified dataframe
So replace this

```
df.str.replace('%', '')
```

by

```
df = df.replace('%', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Sunitha! Unfortunately, I keep getting the error 'DataFrame' object has no string. Would you know why this is showing up?

Comment: Sorry.. Didn't realize you are using pandas dataframes. I have updated my post. Please try the new soln.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, Sunitha!

Comment: should also note that I had to change the colon to a comma

Comment: sorry.. that was a typo... fixed it